# Magento: setting variables via the "Custom Layout Updates" XML on a per-category basis?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'd like to be able to set variables using the "Custom Layout Updates" box which appears under `Manage Categories -> [Some Category] -> Custom Design`, to specify pieces of data which can be used in the category page template `list.phtml`.

So far, I've tried using this:

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setData">
        <name>custom_banner_type</name>
        <value>single</value>
    </action>
    <action method="setData">
        <name>custom_banner_position</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </action>
</reference>
```

But when I try `echo $this->getData("custom_banner_type");` inside `list.phtml` the data is not available.

I've also tried getting the data inside the `_beforeToHtml()` function inside `List.php`, the template's controller, but this also does nothing!

So is there some way I can pass data/variables using the Custom Layout Updates XML? It has to be done through there, because the data will change for every single category so I can't use hard-coded layout files.

Comment: Have a look at this link here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14605/395

Comment: @RohitS Thanks but this didn't help. As far as I can see my syntax is correct and I'm using the correct methods. But the data is still not getting through.

Comment: refresh the cache, and var/cache/* already?

Answer (score 9):

In which layout handle are you doing this? `catalog_category_view` and `catalog_category_layered` should be used.
Maybe you coul use the default Magento way for setting data with XML. Magento sets data in xml with the set function, which I find more readable than setData in XML.

Example:

```
<catalog_category_view>
  <reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setCustomBannerType"><value>single</value></action>
    <action method="setCustomBannerPosition"><value>3</value></action>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

To retrieve the data you could use `$this->getData('custom_banner_type');` but also `$this->getCustomBannerType();` which is the same. If you want to know more about this I would suggest looking at magic methods (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

I don't know if cache is enabled, if so flush the cache and it should work.

Comment: Is the handle <catalog_category_view> necessary if you are already in the custom layout update box of the category in backend?